# Why my form input of type number is not getting any value?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, forms

pleease help.

I am trying to get the value of the input with id **amount_0027634199476**. Whenever I change the value of the field, I am not getting anything through javascript after I click on the submit button which is supposed to send an alert with the input box's value.
**This is my code**:

```
<div class="modal-body">
          <form id="frm_entry_0027634199476" method="post">
                <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='a9wl1mTYjT1FhTmhr41zLoy6H7ay4QPvDXQHuUSNcGcMkrUNVISM7BSvRbVp3RPf' />
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Montant</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                          <input type="number" id="amount_0027634199476" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                <div class="form-group">   
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                              <input type="radio" checked="" value="True" id="optionsRadios1" name="deposit_0027634199476"> <strong>Depot</strong> 
                            </label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                              <input type="radio" value="False" id="optionsRadios2" name="deposit_0027634199476"> <strong>Retrait</strong>
                            </label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="cancel" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">anuller</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="submiter()" >valider</button>
          <script>
          function submiter(){
              x = document.getElementById("amount_0027634199476");
             alert(x.value); 
          }
          </script>
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can I right it? or is it due to the fact that the page where this code lies in includes multiple forms with the same csrf-token?

Comment: Why is this tagged `python`?

Comment: because I am using python through django to generate the IDs of the form's elements

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

https://jsfiddle.net/0pbsxLmw/

```
<<html>
  <body>
  <div class="modal-body">
          <form id="frm_entry_0027634199476" method="post">
                <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='a9wl1mTYjT1FhTmhr41zLoy6H7ay4QPvDXQHuUSNcGcMkrUNVISM7BSvRbVp3RPf' />
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Montant</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                          <input type="number" id="amount_0027634199476" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                <div class="form-group">   
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                              <input type="radio" checked="" value="True" id="optionsRadios1" name="deposit_0027634199476"> <strong>Depot</strong> 
                            </label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                              <input type="radio" value="False" id="optionsRadios2" name="deposit_0027634199476"> <strong>Retrait</strong>
                            </label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="cancel" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">anuller</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="submiter()" >valider</button>
          <script>
          function submiter(){
              x = document.getElementById("amount_0027634199476");
             alert(x.value); 
          }
          </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Alright I just checked and it is also working...Now i'm thinking that the problem is somewhere else in my html code. Can I oast it right here?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution.
**Here it is:**

Since there were multiple auto-generated forms and their *sumbiter()* javascript method to validate and submit the form for each form, I had to make the names of the javascript methods different from each other in order to target the specific javascript method on each onClick event.